# I am attempting to find the Adjusted Odds Ratio using a multivariable logistic regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, logistic-regression

I am working on a multivariable logistic regression model in R. My goal is to compare Mortality for a female cohort group using males as a reference. I have specified males to be 0 and females to be 1. I am having trouble understanding the output and how to calculate the adjusted odds ratio. For some variables I am receiving an odds ratio of 0 and a really large CI. R does throw the error:

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

If anyone could help me understand how to calculate adjusted odds ratio and how to use the multivariable logistic regression using the males as a reference I would greatly appreciate it.

My formula is as follows:

```r
glm(formula = Outcome ~ SEX + DIABETES + STEROID, family = binomial, data = df)
```

Outcome is a post op variable we are trying to predict using certain pre op variables.

Comment: this might be a better question for stat exchange, this seems more statistical than coding

Comment: Agreed that you may be better off on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but my guess without seeing the output is that this is a (quais-)separation problem.  Generally when this happens the coefficients get far away from zero with really big standard errors.  You could try a biased-reduced model (e.g., using the `brglm2` package) which solves the problem according to Firth and colleagues' solution.